# import * as someName from '@angular/core' in angular 2/4/5/6/latter Versions

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

How to use **import * as someName from '@angular/core'** in angular2/4/5/6/latter versions; not that particular package like **@angular/core**, it is any package. I am confusing in this question then how to use it, how to apply it in component, Please help me any one with sample example if you were facing such type of questions in your project.

Comment: Sample example? Have you checked https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-component-properties-with-interpolation

Comment: If you generate angular project using `angular/cli`, you can see the imports over there.

Answer (score 1):

For classic modules, typically those of Angular, you can import them using this syntax : `import {module} from "@angular/core"`.

But if you want examples about third party libraries, I can share some of mine. I had this problem for importing moment library. For my case, I used it like this : 
`import * as moment from "moment";`, then used the methods included in the library, like: `moment(someDate).someMethod;`. It's pretty straight forward.

You can be more specific regarding what you want to use. For example, I had a library called pako which I used like this : `import * as pako from "/path/in/node_modules/pako;"`. Then I used one single method `pako.deflate(someUncompressedData);`. This was not clever because every method from pako was imported, even though I didn't use them (somehow tree shaking was not working properly). So I gained in performance by importing the module I wanted like this : `import {deflate} from "pako/lib/deflate"` and used it like `deflate(uncompressedData);`.

You can look inside node_modules/yourModule to get some insight. You can see how the modules you're trying to import are exported, or what they contain.